# Shopify Liquid Modifier order

Tags: shopify, liquid

If I add multiple modifiers in Shopify Liquid, what order does the code get processed in?

For example:

```
tag_parts.last | capitalize | replace: "-", " "
```

Would it:
Capitalize and then replace the hyphen
or
Replace the hyphen and then capitalize

I have looked quite a bit, but haven't found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The order is from left to right.

So in your case they will be capitalized then replaced.